# Error with file name handling in python

Tags: python, file-io

Minimal working example that shows this error:

```
from os import listdir, getcwd
from os.path import isfile, join, realpath, dirname
import csv

def gd(mypath, myfile):
    # Obtain the number of columns in the data file
    with open(myfile) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
        for i in range(20):
            row_20 = next(reader)
        # Save number of clumns in 'num_cols'.
        num_cols = len(row_20)
        return num_cols

mypath = realpath(join(getcwd(), dirname(__file__)))

# Iterate through all files. Stores name of file in 'myfile'.
for myfile in listdir(mypath):

    if isfile(join(mypath,myfile)) and (myfile.endswith('.dat')):
        num_cols = gd(mypath, myfile)

print(num_cols)
```

I have a single file called 'data.dat' in that folder and `python` returns the error:

```
----> 9     with open(myfile) as f:
....
IOError: [Errno 2] No existe el archivo o el directorio: u'data.dat'
```

Which translates to *No file or directory: u'data.dat'*.

Why is that *u* being added at the beginning of the file name and how do I get the code to correctly parse the file name?

Comment: thats just in the representation ... it means it is a unicode string ... the u  is not actually in the string and certainly is not your problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `u` just indicates that it is a unicode string and is not relevant to the problem.

The file isn't found because you aren't adding the `mypath` in front of the filename - try `with open(join(mypath, myfile)) as f:`

Comment: Thank you, but how do I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `myfile` is just a filename, not the result of `join(mypath,myfile)`.